# Как лучше организовать хранение информации об остатках товаров в интернет-магазине?

Tags: php, интернет-магазин, mysql

Всем привет.

Задача такая: есть интернет-магазин обуви, одна модель обуви существует в нескольких размерах. Как лучше организовать хранение информации об этих остатках в баз данных MySQL? Дайте идею!

Comment: а зачем их ваще где то хранить? остаток - это товаров меньше Х. т.е это обычный селект с условием, можно сделать отображение (view), на крайний случай.

Comment: Хранить их нужно, чтобы не дать пользователю заказать товар, которого нет на складе.

Answer (score 3):

Отдельная таблица, где хранится ID модели, размер и остаток.

Comment: Такая идея пришла мне в голову в первую очередь. Но мне не нравятся запросы, с помощью которых эту информацию придется обновлять.
Больше никаких идей?

Comment: А чем вам запрос не нравится?
первый запрос делает запрос к основной таблице и выводит инфу о модели а второй запрос на основе ID получает с дополнительной таблицы какие размеры доступны.

Comment: Т.е. ничего лучше не придумать? (

Comment: А смысл создавать еще одну таблицу с, по сути, дубированием информации? Не нужно плодить таблицы. @savro прав, запрос по id товара и сравнение результата с 0
К тому же, лишняя таблица, в случае, если вы делаете прямой запро из кода, а не через какой-либо API, только усложнит восприятие: "зачем тут еще одна таблица? Что автор имел в виду, когда ее создавал и нет ли тут каких-то неочевидных мотивов?"

Comment: Смысл в отдельной таблице есть - это не обсуждается. К тому же, дублирования нет. А восприятие других кодеров - это проблема других кодеров...)

Answer (score 2):

Если число разных размеров невелико, то можно сделать одну запись на каждую модель и хранить остатки разных размеров в полях этой записи. И даже если у каких-то отдельных моделей будет расширенный набор размеров, то для таких моделей можно добавлять вторую (фиктивную) запись. У неё не будет заполнено ни название модели, ни какие-либо другие поля, описывающие отдельную модель. Будет лишь ID, сохранённый в одном из полей основной записи, и остатки дополнительных размеров. При этом минимальный размер из дополнительной записи должен быть интерпретирован, как размер, следующий за максимальным из основной.

Comment: Интересный вариант, но дает лишнюю нагрузку на мускул-сервер. Сам бы не использовал и другим не рекомендую...

Comment: Сам бы я тоже так делать не стал. Но, как я понял, вы хотите странного. Предложил самое странное, что смог придумать. А если по-хорошему, то надо делать либо в двух таблицах (как пишут выше), либо в одной - по отдельной записи на каждый размер. Во втором случае информация, описывающая саму модель, может храниться в любом из размеров. Например, в том, который поступает на склад и добавляется в базу первым. Для получения списка моделей нужно выбрать записи, где название модели NOT NULL.

Comment: Ничего странного я не хочу...) Просто пытаюсь преобразовать витрину в интернет-магазин с наименьшими затратами символов...)

Comment: Тогда нужно просто выбрать из двух банальных вариантов. Первый более канонический. Он соответствует 3-й нормальной форме. А вариант с одной таблицей ей не соответствует, но зато он попроще.

Comment: На счет простоты не согласен, скорее описан забавный "костыль". Но всё равно, спасибо за идею - любые идеи помогают найти идеальное решение.

Comment: Под простым вариантом я, конечно же, имел в виду не то извращение, которое описал в самом ответе, а вариант из второго коммента к нему. По сути, это более-менее удачная пародия на 1-ю нормальную форму. Проще может быть только честная 1-я форма. Но она в данной ситуации совершенно неуместна.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант добавить 3 таблицы: табл_свойства, табл_значения свойств, табл_связь значения с товаром.

И потом уже спокойно набивать свойства со значениями (например цвет{красный синий зеленый}, размер{41, 42, 43} итд.).

Привязав несколько свойств к товару, получим товар с несколькими модификациями.

Плюс - не нужно добавлять поля в таблицах для новых свойств товара, не нужно плодить записи с товарами.

Минус - сложная логика связей.

PS есть реализация данной логики на тяжко нагруженных проектах. На скорость выборки для фильтра влияет положительно.